# How to associate responses from axios.all with a key

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to use axios.all to make multiple calls from an array of objects so I can associate the response with a specific key:

```
axiosArrayOfObjects = [
    {uniqueID1: axios.get1},
    {uniqueID2: axios.get2}
    {uniqueID3: axios.get3}
]


for (var i = 0; i < axiosArrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
  for (var key in axiosArrayOfObjects[i])
    var value = axiosGetRequestArray[i][key]

    axios.all(value).then(axios.spread((...response) => {
      console.log(response[0])
    }))
}
```

But I am getting an error that says "TypeError: object is not iterable"

Is there another way I can associate each response from an axios.all request with a specific ID? I need to update an object in the database with the response of the calls.

Comment: might be related: `console.log[response[0]]` --> `console.log(response[0])`

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, still have the same problem.

Comment: the only place I can see that could throw `Object is not iterable` is the `for..in`, so I'm guessing the actual data you have for `axiosArrayOfObjects` has a bad format (one or more values which are not objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through the objects' keys, the problem is that you're calling `axios.all(..)` with `value` which is a single request not an array of requests. You need to do something like this:

```
const axiosArrayOfObjects = [
    {uniqueID1: axios.get1},
    {uniqueID2: axios.get2}
    {uniqueID3: axios.get3}
]


const map = axiosArrayOfObjects.reduce((a, c) => {
  Object.entries(o).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    a.ids.push(key);
    a.requests.push(value);
  });
  return a;
}, {
  requests: [],
  ids: []
})

axios.all(map.requests).then(axios.spread((...response) => {
  responses.forEach((response, index) => {
    console.log('request id', map.ids[index], 'response', response)
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `Promise.all` here ?

```js
const axiosArrayOfObjects = [
    { id: '1', get: axios.get1},
    { id: '2', get: axios.get2}
    { id: '3', get: axios.get3}
]

/* array of promises */
const requests = axiosArrayOfObjects.map(item => item.get());

const result = await Promise.all(requests);
console.log(result);
/* array of results, order is the save as in `axiosArrayOfObjects`,
so you can use indexes to match elements of two arrays */

/* without await */
Promise.all(requests).then(result => console.log(result));
```